# How prove $f(x)$ is monotonous , if $f'(x)=g[f(x)]$

Tags: analysis, functions

**Question:**

> Let $f(x)$ be a derivative, and there exsit $g(x)$ be such that:
>   $$f'(x)=g[f(x)]$$
>   Show that $f(x)$ is monotonic.

This problem is from Xie Hui Min analysis problems book in china ,and the 
The author only give the hint: use contradiction.

[image]

My idea: Assume there exist $x,y$ such that: 
$$f(x)=f(y), x\neq y$$
Then:

$$f'(x)=g(f(x))\Longrightarrow f'(y)=g(f(y))=g(f(x))=f'(x).$$
Then I can't continue. Thank you

Comment: I suppose $g$ is assumed to be continuous?

Comment: if $g$ not continuous,then have counexample?

Comment: You won't be able to prove strict monotonicity. For instance, if $f(x) = 1$ (which is a derivative) and $g(x) = 0$ you have $f'(x) = g(f(x))$ for all $x$. Here $f$ is monotone.

Comment: @UmbertoP.yes,My problem is prove $f$ is monotone,not strict monotonicity

Comment: OK, but starting with $f(x) = f(y)$ for $x \not= y$ won't lead anywhere since it is consistent with the conclusion.

Comment: @Macavity then $g(f(x))=2|x|$

Comment: @Macavity No matter how you define $g(x)$ for $x<0$, since $f(x)\geq 0$. $f(x)=x^2$ simply doesn't work.

Comment: Missed that....

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280804/solutions-of-autonomous-odes-are-monotonic   this may help.

Answer (score 4):

If $f(x)$ exists everywhere and $g(y)$ exists over the entire range of $f(x)$, then $f'(x)$ exists everywhere and $f(x)$ must therefore be continuous everywhere.  We'll assume this is the case.

Assume $f(x)$ has a local maximum at $x_0$:

1. $f'(x_0) = 0$
2. There exists $x_1 < x_0$ where $f(x_1) < f(x_0)$
3. There exists $x_2 > x_0$ where $f(x_2) < f(x_0)$

Also, there are no other extrema between $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Pick $x_3$ and $x_4$ such that $x_1 < x_3 < x_0 < x_4 < x_2$ and $f(x_3) < f(x_0)$ and $f(x_4) = f(x_3)$.  Since $f(x)$ is continuous, this must be possible.

Since there are no other extrema between $x_3$ aned $x_4$, we must have $f'(x) \geq 0$ for $x_3 < x < x_0$ and $f'(x) \leq 0$ for $x_0 < x < x_4$.

Thus, we must have $g(y) \geq 0$ for $f(x_3) < y < f(x_0)$ and $g(y) \leq 0$ for $f(x_0) > y > f(x_4)$.  But $f(x_3) = f(x_4)$ so these two ranges are the same.  We must have $g(y) = 0$ for $f(x_3) < 0 < f(x_0)$, which would mean we must have  $f(x_3) = f(x_0)$, which contradicts our original assumption that there is a local maximum.

The same argument holds for the assumption of a local minimum.

So $f(x)$ cannot have any local maximum or local minimum anywhere, and thus must be monotonic.

Comment: Why are there no other extrema between $x_3$ and $x_4$? Note that $f(x)=x^4\sin^2(\frac{1}{x})$ with $f(0)=0$ is differentiable and has a local minimum at $x=0$, but there are also infinitely many other local minima in any interval around $0$.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that it is not assumed that $f'$ is continuous.

Comment: @ajotatxe That happens if $g$ is assumed to be continuous..... So maybe with that extra assumption it works...... But even then $f(x)=x^{2n}\sin^2(\frac{1}{x})$ with $n$ large enough still has infinitely many local mins around $0$ and continuous derivative...

Comment: for this $$f(x)=-x^2\left(2+\sin{\dfrac{1}{x}}\right),x\neq 0$$ and $$f(x)=0,x=0$$

Comment: Note that for $f(x) = x^4 \sin^2(1/x)$, there are many maxima.  Pick any one of them (other than $x=0$) and apply the steps above to reach a contradiction.  Thus, that function cannot satisfy the criteria.  Any function with even a single well-behaved extremum cannot satisfy the criteria for this problem.

Comment: @user3294068,I think you methods is someone wrong

Comment: An informal explanation of my answer:  In the vicinity of a (local, isolated) maximum: a little bit to the left, the value will be slightly less than the maximum and increasing.  A little to the right, it will be slightly less than the maximum and decreasing.  But $f'(x) = g(f(x))$ and $f(x)$ is the same in both regions (slightly less than the maximum), so it cannot be increasing in one and decreasing in the other.  Therefore the function cannot have any maxima (or, by similar argument, minima).

Answer (score 0):

Let's begin by assuming that $f'(a) > 0$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$. From this, we can deduce that $f(x) > f(a)$ for every $x > a$. To see why, suppose for the sake of contradiction that there exists some $y > a$ such that $f(y) = f(a)$. Now, let's define $z$ as the infimum of the set $\{y: f(y) = f(a) \text{ and } y > a\}$. It follows that $f'(z)$ must be non-positive. However, this contradicts our initial assumption that $f'(a) > 0$, as it implies that $f'(z) = f'(a) > 0$.

Now, let's assume that $f$ is not a monotonous function, meaning there exist $\alpha < \beta$ such that $f(\alpha)f(\beta) < 0$. Without loss of generality, let's say $f'(\alpha) > 0$ and $f'(\beta) < 0$.

By the earlier deduction, we know that $f(\beta) > f(\alpha)$. Within the interval $[\alpha, \beta]$, there exists a greatest value $f(\gamma)$ of $f$, such that $f(\gamma) > f(\beta)$, where $\gamma \in (\alpha, \beta)$. Consequently, we can choose the greatest $\alpha_1 \in (\alpha, \gamma)$ such that $f(\alpha_1) = f(\beta)$, and thus, $f(x) \geq f(\beta)$ for every $x \in [\alpha_1, \gamma]$.

By the Mean Value Theorem, there is some $\alpha_2 \in (\alpha_1, \gamma)$ such that $f'(\alpha_2) = \frac{f(\gamma) - f(\alpha_1)}{\gamma - \alpha_1} > 0$. Since $\beta > \gamma > \alpha_2$, we have $f(\beta) > f(\alpha_2) \geq f(\beta)$, which leads to a contradiction.