# Usage of intermediate value theorem in proof

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, proof-explanation

Edit: As explained in the comments and in the answer, the IVT was not used to show the derivative but for the statement right before it ($g(t)<g(v)$)...

---

In [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1280804/851484) I came across a reasoning which used the intermediate value theorem and somehow makes conclusions about the derivate of the function. I have summed up the part of [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1281823/851484) which *I think* is crucial to possibly follow the reasoning:

> ($g$ is differentiable.) Since $g(t)>g(v)$ for $t\in[c,v)$ by the intermediate value theorem, it follows that $g′(v)\le 0$.

Please refer to the [full answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1281823/851484) if more context is needed. Unfortunately, I don't see how the IVT is linked to the derivative.

In addition I tried to clarify the answer by suggesting the following:

> Since $g(t) > g(v)$ for $t\in [c,v)$ we know $\frac{g(v)-g(t)}{v-t}<0$, thus with $t\to v^-$ and because $g$ is differentiable, it follows that $g'(v) \le 0$.

However, my edit was rejected and I also can't comment on the answer (reputation).

1. Can you help me understand why the IVT proves the point in the first place?
2. Is my alternative reasoning correct?

Comment: As I understand it from a quick reading of that answer, the intermediate value theorem is used to show that  $g(t)>g(v)$ for $t\in[c,v)$, not to show that  $g′(v)\le 0$.

Comment: @MartinR Ok, I think I indeed misread the comma and think you're right in that the IVT was probably used to show $g(t)>g(v)$ for $t\in[c,v)$. However, I still don't see how the IVT helps to prove that point since the IVT is an existence theorem. I would argue that the fact follows from the construction of $v$ and that $g(c)>g(a)$.

Comment: Actually it says $g(t) > g(a)$ for $t \in [c, v)$. Otherwise $g(t) < g(a)$ for some $t$ in that interval, and IVT shows that $g(t) = g(a)$ for some $t$, contradiction the definition of $v$ as the minimum of $M$.

Comment: oh, yeah ok, now I do see how one can bring the IVT into play. Thank you! From a sketch and my intuition I thought it was "clear" that $g(t)>g(a)=g(v)$  for $t\in[c,v)$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that part of the answer we have

- $a < c < b$ with $g(a) \le g(b) < g(c)$,
- $M = \{t\in (c,b] : g(t) = g(a)\}$,
- $v = \min M > c$,

and the claim is that $g(t) > g(a)$ for $c \le t < v$.

It is clear from the definition of $v$ as the minimum of $M$ that $g(t) \ne g(a)$ for $c \le t < v$, so we must exclude the case that $g(t_1) < g(a)$ for some $t_1 \in [c, v)$. This is the part where the IVT is used: Since $g(c) > g(a)$, the IVT would imply that $g(t_0) = g(a)$ for some $t_0$ between $c$ and $t_1$, contradicting the definition of $M$.

The next step is to conclude that $g'(v) \le 0$, and that is done exactly as you argued.