# Show that every solution of the differential equation is monotonic

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity, monotone-functions

I just started learning ODE and found this problem. Can anyone help me prove it.

> Let $f : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Show that every solution of the differential equation $x' = f(x)$ is monotonic

My work until now

$x'(t)=f(x(t))$

$ \frac{dx}{dt}=f(x(t)) $

$ \int{\frac{dx}{f(x(t))}}=\int{dt}+C=t+C $

Derivative by $t$:
$ \frac{d}{dt}\int{\frac{dx}{f(x(t))}}=\frac{dt}{dt}=1 $

$ \frac{d}{dt}F(x(t))=1 $ <-- Chainrule

$ F'(x(t))\cdot{}x'(t)=1 $

$ \frac{1}{f(x(t))}\cdot{}x'(t)=1 $

If $x$ were not monotonic, it would have at least 1 extreme due to continuity and $ x'(t_0)=0. $ If we now insert this, we get:$0=1$

This is a false statement, so there is no $ t_0, $ for which $ x'(t_0)=0 $ holds, hence $x$ is monotonic.

Is my way correct?

Comment: I think the statement of the problem is true because $f$ is defined on all of $\mathbb R$. You do not have to go that long route to arrive at $ \frac{1}{f(x(t))}\cdot{}x'(t)=1$ because that follows directly from the ODE. What if $f(x(t_0))=0$ ? I don't see how you deduce $0=1$ from that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that solutions to $\dot x=f(x)$ are monotonic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4339918/prove-that-solutions-to-dot-x-fx-are-monotonic)