$x' = x \, \log(1 + x^2)$
I'm trying to solve the following problem.

Consider the IVP $x' = x \log(1 + x^2), \, x(0) = 1$. Prove that the maximal solution is defined on all the real line and it is stricly positive and increasing.

My attempt: By Peano's Theorem and Zorn's Lemma, we have a maximal solution $x: (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ of this IVP (for $a \neq b$ both possible not finite). As the ODE is an autonomous first order we know that the solutions are monotonic, then, as $x(0) = 1 > 0$, if there is some $\tau \in (a,b)$ such that $x(\tau) < 0$, we conclude that x is not monotonic: Absurd. Follows that x is non-negative, and moreover must be stricly positive, because $x \equiv 0$ is a solution of the ODE. Then for all $t \in (a,b)$, we have $x'(t) = x(t) \log(1+x(t)^2) > 0$, i.e., x is also increasing.
As $x \mapsto x \log(1 + x^2)$ is countinuos, I know that if a or b are finite then $\lim_{t \to a^+} x(t) = \lim_{t \to b^-} x(t) = + \infty$. For a, this contradicts with x increasing and stricly positive, so $a = - \infty$. Now for b, I'm struggling to conclude that $b = + \infty$, maybe is something about the growing rate of the logarithm function, but I don't know how to formalize.
Anyone can help me finish this exercise? Thanks.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4339918/prove-that-solutions-to-dot-x-fx-are-monotonic?noredirect=1&lq=1

The solutions of the DE are given implicitly by
$$ \int_1^x \dfrac{ds}{s \ln(1+s^2)} = t $$
Now the question comes down to, do the improper integrals $$ \int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{ds}{s \ln(1+s^2)}$$ and $$\int_{1}^\infty \dfrac{ds}{s \ln(1+s^2)}$$
converge or diverge?
You might note that $$ \frac{1}{s \ln(1+s^2)} \sim \frac{1}{s^3} \ \text{as}\ s \to 0 $$
while
$$ \frac{1}{s \ln(1+s^2)} \sim \frac{1}{2 s \ln(s)} \ \text{as}\ s \to +\infty$$

I don't get the final part, the integral $\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{ds}{2s \ln(s)} = \frac{1}{2} \ln(\ln(x)) |_0^{+\infty}$ does not converge

Yes, that's the point.  So as $x \to \infty$, $t \to \infty$.  If it converged, the solution would blow up at a finite $t$.

Get it. Thanks.

You can use comparison. Observe that
$$
x\log (1+x^2)\le x\log 2x^2=x\log 2+2x\log x
$$
for $x\ge 1$. Therefore, the local solution to your IVP exists as least as long as the solution to the IVP
$$
x'=x\log 2 +2x\log x;\qquad x(0)=1
$$
exists. But the latter is defined for all $t\ge 0$ because the improper integral
$$
\int\limits_1^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x\log 2+2x\log x}
$$
is divergent.
