# Proving that function proportional to derivative is monotonic indirectly

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

The solution to the differential equation $f'(x)=Cf(x)$ is $f(x)=Ae^{Cx}$ The function $f(x)$ is monotonic. $$f(x)=Ae^{Cx}$$ $$f'(x)=ACe^{Cx}$$ $$\operatorname{sgn}(f'(x))=\operatorname{sgn}(AC)\operatorname{sgn}(e^{Cx})$$

$$\operatorname{sgn}(f'(x))=\operatorname{sgn}(AC)\cdot1$$

$$\operatorname{sgn}(f'(x))=\operatorname{sgn}(AC)=constant$$

This approach to proving the monotonicity depends on solving the diff eq. Is there a way to prove that any function that satisfies $f'(x)=Cf(x)$ is monotonic without solving for $f(x)$?

Comment: If it was not monotonic, there would be a point at which $f'(x_{+})$ is positive value, and a point at which $f'(x_{-})$ is negative. By intermediate value theorem we have a point $x_{0}$ at which $f'(x_{0}) = 0$.  We can derive the original equation to get $f^{(n+1)} (x_{0})= C f^{(n)} (x_{0})$. From this we get $f^{(n)}(x_{0}) = 0$ for all $n$ and by Taylor series $f(x)$ = 0

Comment: How about first rule out the existence of  $x$ such that $f(x) = 0$ and then rewrite it as:
$$(\ln f(x))' = C.$$
So $\ln f$ is monotonic and so you apply $\exp(\cdot)$ now to get $f$ is monotonic ? Once you know that $f$ cannot vanish, then it follows that sign of $f$ is constant (for otherwise you would get a zero of $f$ from the mean value theorem) and so you can now WLOG assume $f > 0$ to enable taking of the natural logarithm.

Comment: @user3257842 one cannot a priori assume that $f$ is anything more than a $C^1$ function, although it should be possible to prove the existence of higher derivatives. Even then analyticity is a stronger assumption than smoothness.

Comment: @user3257842 there are functions for which at some point *all* derivatives are zero, however they are not constant zero.

Comment: @dezdichado: $f\in C^\infty$, since if $f\in C^1$, then $f'' = C^2 f$, etc - you can inductively get arbitrary high derivatives, and they all are a multiple of $f$, which is $C^1$, so in turn differentiable one more time.

Comment: also, it looks like a general question is answered at  [solutions to autonomous ODE are monotonic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280804/solutions-of-autonomous-odes-are-monotonic?rq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that $f$ is smooth and not monotone. Then, there exists $x_1<x_2<x_3$ so that either: 1) $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$ and $f(x_2)>f(x_3)$; or 2) $f(x_1)>f(x_2)$ and $f(x_2)<f(x_3)$. In case 1), by the mean-value theorem, $f'(x^{\star})\geq 0$ for some $x^{\star}\in\left[x_1,x_2\right]$ and $f'(x^{\star\star})\leq 0$ for some $x^{\star\star}\in\left[x_2,x_3\right]$. Therefore, by the intermediate value theorem, $f'(x)=0$ for some $x\in\left[x_1,x_3\right]$. But this violates the uniqueness of solutions to the referred ODE -- the only solution with $f'(x)=0$ for some $x$ is the identically zero solution, i.e., $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

The same conlcusion holds if we choose case 2).

Comment: You could even simplify the first part. If $f$ is not monotonic, since $f$ is smooth, by the intermediate value theorem there must be a sign change of $f'$, i.e. a point $x_\star$ such that $f'(x_\star)=0$.

Comment: I think this is the solution - even though it's using a much stronger theorem.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: Indeed. I have just broken this way to make sure. Thank you.

Comment: @dezdichado: I believe it should be a minimal one. I have not checked the other answers, but at a glance, they seem to be operating at the microscopics of the mean/intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Are you using any deeper theorem on uniqueness of solution to ODE? Otherwise it isn't at all obvious how vanishing of derivative at a single point leads to the solution $f(x) =0$ identically.

Comment: Yes, uniqueness (over all $\mathbb{R}$) of solutions to the ODE when the underlying vector field is (globally) Lipschitz. There might be a simpler version for the specific case of a linear ODE.

Answer (score 3):

The differential equation $f'(x) =Cf(x) $ is trivial when $C=0$ with the solution $f$ being a constant function.

So let $C\neq 0$. In that case there is another trivial solution $f(x) =0$ for all $x$. So we look for solutions $f$ which are not identically $0$.

We prove that if there is a number $a$ such that $f(a) \neq 0$ then $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x$.

Consider $g(x) =f(a+x) f(a-x) $ and then $$g'(x) =f(a-x) f'(a+x) - f(a+x) f'(a-x) =Cf(a-x) f(a+x) - Cf(a+x) f(a-x) =0$$ so that $g$ is a constant which equals $g(0)=f(a)f(a)>0$. Thus the product $f(a+x) f(a-x) $ is non-zero for all $x$ and hence $f(x) $ doesn't vanish for any value of $x$.

Since $f$ is differentiable, it is continuous as well and then because of intermediate value property it maintains a constant sign. Then $f'(x) =Cf(x) $ maintains a constant sign and the function $f$ is therefore strictly monotone.

Comment: +1 for the idea of $g(x)$

Comment: @TheSimpliFire: OK let me be honest here, the idea comes from an exercise in Spivak's *Calculus*. The purpose of exercise is to develop a theory of exponential function from the differential equation $f'(x) =f(x) $.

Answer (score 2):

First, assume that $f'(x)=Cf(x)$ then assume $f(b)>f(b+\epsilon_0)<f(b+2\epsilon_0)$, just a way to say that the function is not monotonic for when $\epsilon_0>0$ for a infinitesimally small $\epsilon_0$.

We have that $f'(x) = \displaystyle\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{f(x+\epsilon)-f(x)}{\epsilon} = Cf(x)$, this implies that $f'(b)=Cf(b)<0.$ Applying this again to $f'(b+\epsilon)$ we get that $f'(b+\epsilon_0)=Cf(b+\epsilon_0)>0$. However, this presents contradictions relating to the sign of C. We can assume that the signs of $f(b), f(b+\epsilon_0),$ and $f(b+2\epsilon_0)$ are the same since they are in neighborhoods of each other. If $f(b)=0$ then consider a different point in the function.

Comment: The contradiction implies that the inequality between the points cannot hold and therefore must be monotonic.

Comment: Your epsilon in the first line is just one number or you are asserting a an entire interval ? Because the claim you are claiming in the second paragraphs have the whole continuum of epsilons approaching to $0.$