Proving monotonicity in an ODE
We are required to prove that $y(x)$ is monotonic for $x \in (0,\infty) $ given that $y' = Ay - By^3$ , $y(0) > 0 , A> 0 , B>0$
Progress :
I took two cases
Case 1 :
$ y(0) > \sqrt{\frac{A}{B}}$ . I was able to show that $y^{(n)} = 0$ , for $n > 0$ if $y = \sqrt{\frac{A}{B}}$ . So we have $y'(0)< 0$ ,hence $y$ will keep decreasing till  $y = \sqrt{\frac{A}{B}}$ , after which it will stop changing.
Similarly we get a second case , but this argument doesn't seem rigorous enough , especially the part "it will stop changing". Is there a theorem for this that I don't know ?

Solutions of $y'=f(y)$ are always monotone, see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280804/solutions-of-autonomous-odes-are-monotonic
