# Why should this result be true? If $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, $g$ is continuous, and $f'(t) = g(f(t)),$ then $f$ is monotonic.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> If $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, $g$ is continuous, and
> $f'(t) = g(f(t)),$ then $f$ is monotonic.

Example 1: Suppose $g(x) = x \Rightarrow f' = f.$ Then $f = ce^x$ which is indeed monotonic.

Example 2: Suppose $g(x) = x^n \Rightarrow f' = f^n$ for $n \ne 1.$ Then $df/f^n = dx \Rightarrow x+C = f^{1-n}/(1-n) \Rightarrow f = ((1-n)x + C)^{1/(1-n)},$ monotonic again.

It seems bizarre that $g$ can be anything we want, and yet the result will be true. Since $f$ is continuous, it suffices to prove $f$ is injective. So suppose $f(a) = f(b)$ with $a<b.$

Avenue 1: Then $f'(a) = g(f(a)) = g(f(b)) = f'(b).$ But what's next? This seems like a dead end.

Avenue 2: There exists $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f'(c) = 0$ by Rolle's Theorem. Thus, $g(f(c)) = 0.$ But what's next? Looks like another dead end again.

Is there a 3rd avenue? I've been looking for one. Until I find it, I cannot believe the result.

Update: The answer [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h408622p2284371) solves my question. The question also appeared previously on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/812593/how-prove-fx-is-monotonous-if-fx-gfx), but I do not like the method used there since it seems to assume $f'$ is continuous.

Comment: if $f$ is monotonic, how can $f(a)=f(b)$ for $a<b$? If $f$ is constant then $g$ is always zero? You try to prove by contradiction?

Comment: @MikaelHelin Yes, I am trying a proof by contradiction.

Comment: I'd like to flag as a duplicate of this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/812593/631742 but I don't have the time to check the answer that is given there

Comment: The reason your original proof by contradiction fails is because constant functions also satisfy monotonicity, aka $f$ being a root of $g$

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch How did you find this problem? When I posted my question, nothing showed up in the "similar questions" box. I need to get better at hunting for duplicates.

Comment: @Displayname Use https://approach0.xyz :)

Comment: Cool :) I was clueless about possibility searching Latex.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch My question is too long and I got "Too many math keywords in query. (return code #6)". Also, why isn't this website advertised on MSE? It could be a better resource than the built-in "similar questions" field.

Comment: @BrianMoehring There is no Lipschitz condition though

Comment: @Displayname Just enter `f'(x)=g(f(x))` in the raw query field. And you'll have to ask MSE admins ;)

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I see now.  The examples OP used for $g$ were all too "nice" for the general case, I suppose (some "local Lipschitz" condition)...

Comment: @Displayname "but I do not like the method used there since it seems to assume $f'$ is continuous" -- Since $f'=g\circ f$ is the composition of continuous functions, it _is_ continuous...

Comment: @Displayname: *“Also, why isn't this website advertised on MSE?”* – Actually Approach0 *is* advertised in the top-rated answer to [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265).

Answer (score 1):

This is an explanation of an answer found [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h408622p2284371), which works but leaves out a few details.

Suppose $f(a) = f(b), a<b.$ It will suffice to show $f$ is constant on $[a,b].$ Let $\gamma$ be the path parameterized by $\gamma(t) = f(t), t \in [a,b].$ Then $$\int_a^b f'(t)^2 \, dt = \int_a^b g(f(t))f'(t) = \int_{\gamma} g(z) \, dz = 0$$ since $g$ is continuous and $\gamma$ is a closed loop due to the fact that $\gamma(a) = f(a) = f(b) = \gamma(b).$

Thus, $f'(t) = 0$ on $[a,b],$ which implies $f$ is constant on $[a,b].$